# Sorting entities by their @OneToMany relationship property with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on Spring Boot web application which uses Spring Data JPA for its persistance layer. When retrieving entities from repository I'm using Spring's Data JPA `Sort` object to sort them. It works when I'm sorting by retrieved entity property or by it's @OneToOne relationship object property, but **I would like to use it to sort by one of the @OneToMany relationship object properties.**

Let's explain with an example: suppose I have entity object `Author` which has one to many relationship with another entity `Book`. My entity classes in simplest form would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books;

    <constructor, getters, setters etc.>
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    <constructor, getters, setters etc.>
}
```

now, when I'm retrieving authors with Spring's repository interface I'm passing Sort object to it like this one:

`new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id")`

which gives me results sorted by author id ascending. I would like to pass something like this:

`new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "books.title")`

Let's say I have this data in the database (simplified table just to show example):

```
author  | book_title
---------------------
Andrew  | Letter C
Barbara | Letter A
Andrew  | Letter B
Barbara | Letter D
```

The resulting list would be Barbara (her book "Letter A" is first after sorting by book title) then Andrew.

Passing `new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "books.title")` right now results in "Barbara, Andrew, Andrew, Barbara" - which means there are duplicates on resulting list - I would like results to be distinct.

I **do not** want to use `@OrderBy` on collection in Author as I'm not interested in actual books order - only the authors.

I **do not** want to sort results with JPQL on repository level with `@Query` (it would be probably possible with some JPQL subquery and virtual field maybe), as I need it to be able to accept sortable fileds dynamically (it may be title now, but isbn number on other case and my API should be able to take one or the other).

It **has to** work with Spring Specification API which I'm using to filter results.

Is it possible?

Comment: *right now results in "Barbara, Andrew, Andrew, Barbara"* - And what is the expected output? I think that the output covers the requirements.

Comment: I would like it to be distinct, so no duplicates, just Barbara then Andrew and that would be whole list in this case (also added this line to the question).

Comment: I think this is all you need - *findDistinctBy* : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540789/select-distinct-as-query-method

Comment: You can check the pointed Spring discussion from the given thread here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-744

Comment: You can fetch your authors with casual `findAll()` and then maintain them in TreeSet with overridden Comparator.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question, but I found this answer:

```
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("value ASC") // sort by value ASC
private List<PropertyDefinition> propertyDefinitions;
```

Check the answer in this link:
[Spring Data JPA sorting on nested collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862967/spring-data-jpa-sorting-on-nested-collection)

It solve my issue.